# kubectl to allow user to only to copy files in and out of the pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac, kubernetes-pod, kubeconfig

I have a Kubernetes cluster where my application is deployed.
there are some other users they should only be able to copy files into and from a pod. Using kubectl cp command. 
This user context should not allow the user to do any other operations on the cluster other than kubectl cp.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl cp` internally uses `exec`. There is no way to provide permission to only copy but you can provide only `exec` permission.

Create a role with permission to `pods/exec`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-exec
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

Create a Rolebinding to assign the above role to a `user`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-exec-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: pod-exec
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: user
```

Comment: looks helpful will explore more on this

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use kubectl cp, instead run a sidecar container with an sftp or rsync server. That will give you better control at all levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opa and admission controller which only permit to run api manifest has a specific label like "cp" or "username" etc. and also benefits from gatekeeper

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJgaGJm9NJE&t=3040s